# Can't make space in between hamburger - Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I tried using `space-y-2` and `leading` but I still can't put gaps between them.

```html
<a href="" class="bg-blue-dark lg:hidden">
    <span class="block w-7 h-1 mb-1"></span>
    <span class="block w-7 h-1 mb-1"></span>
    <span class="block w-7 h-1"></span>                    
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your current code, there is space between your hamburger bars because you have used the margin-bottom class i.e `mb-1`.

Another approach would be to make the bars flex items, then arrange them column-wise and justify the content. Remember to add a certain height to your flex box container.

```html
    <a href="" class="bg-blue-dark lg:hidden h-5 flex flex-col justify-between">
         <span class="block w-7 h-1"></span>
         <span class="block w-7 h-1"></span>
         <span class="block w-7 h-1"></span>                    
    </a>
```

*If `bg-blue-dark` is your custom class to add colour to the bars then add it to the `<span>` tags instead of the `<a>` tag.